# I like to execute a method from HP Display LiteSaver

Tags: vbscript, wmi

The Display LiteSaver gives me this information:

HP Display LiteSaver installs a WMI Provider which creates a WMI object called `Win32_MonitorPowerSaving` in the `root\CIMV2` namespace.

The WMI object has (among others) the following method:
`PowerOffNow` (no parameters are given).

I'm completely new to WMI but wrote this in VBScript anyway:

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:root\CIMV2:Win32_DisplayPowerSaving")`
Set objMethod = objWMI.ExecMethod_("PowerOffNow")
```

I found out that `Win32_MonitorPowerSaving` should be `Win32_DisplayPowerSaving`.

Apparently the `ExecMethod_` is totally wrong.

So what would be right in order to execute this method?

Comment: Try `objShare.PowerOffNow`.

Comment: Invalid method Parameter(s) Code: 8004102F

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks Ansgar

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further. This seems to be a HP-specific component (and not a commonly used one at that), so you'll have to take it to them.

Comment: I called them but they left me in the cold.

Comment: Well, I now know that the culprit is: how to execute a method with no parameters in WMI.